# Decoration Windows is conflict with the Unity plugin

Tags: unity, plugins

hello after upgrade to 16.04 my compiz crash Unity top bar, side bar, and window decorations are missing I tried enable Windows Decoration in ccsm but it makes conflict with Unity Plugin
I tried reinstall compiz ubuntu-desktop but nothing works
know someone the solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: Disable compiz and reset unity - http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration . Perhaps you can then re-enable compiz not sure.

Comment: rm -rf ~/.gconf ~/.gconfd ~/.metacity ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/dconf

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

unity --reset

doesn't work

Comment: disable compiz and file a bug report. Failed upgrades can be difficult to fix, does it work with a new user ?

Comment: with the guest session is the same

Comment: Sounds like a failed upgrade. Does it work with a live boot from a 16.04 flash drive ? If so a fresh install is going to be faster easier and more reliable then debugging a failed upgrade. Your data in /home will be preserved, but back up just in case.